# ag-grid-community vs ag-grid-enterprise new Grid

Tags: node.js, ag-grid

I have a Node client-side application with the latest ag-grid version.

I was using ag-grid-community without any issues with this require line
const {Grid} = require('ag-grid-community');
and this new
new Grid(agGridDiv, agGridOptions);

but if I change the require to 
const {Grid} = require('ag-grid-enterprise');
the new fails with exception 'Grid is not a constructor'

How can I fix this? I have tried various changes such as new Grid.Grid etc but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

**For latest 23.1.1 version [this page](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-npm/):**

```
// ECMA 5 - using nodes require() method
const AgGrid = require('ag-grid-enterprise');
```

Another way to follow [this guide](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-set-license/#installing-ag-grid-enterprise), it all depends on which repository you download the dependencies from.

```
import {Grid, GridOptions} from '@ag-grid-community/core';
import {LicenseManager} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/core';

// or
const {Grid, GridOptions} = require('@ag-grid-community/core');
```

I used `core` and it worked for import.

**For old version:**

Grid, like everything else, needs to be imported from ag-grid-community.

1) ag-grid-enterprise is pure additive functionality for ag-grid-community.

2) You will use ag-grid-enterprise via the ag-grid-community api not explicit. Use ag-grid-enterprise for LicenseManager only.

**Off-topic:**

I would recommend starting with the old version, since the source code of the new version is minified and it will be more difficult for you to understand many nontrivial nuances.